# Ajax call to asp.net POST method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Recently I have encountered a problem while calling ASP.NET POST Web Method from jQuery AJAX. However, every time I run this program the AJAX call responds with `error: undefined`

```
var departmentBO = {
    dept_id: "",
    dept_name: "",
    msg: "",
    isException: ""
};

function updateDepartment() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(departmentBO),
        url: 'AdminPanel.aspx/UpdateDepartmentNameJSON',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Department Name Updated');
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert(xhr.responsetext);
        }
    });
}
```

```csharp
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateDepartmentNameJSON(DepartmentsBO departmentBO)
{
    string jsonOutput = null;
    try
    {
        jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("It is Working");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return jsonOutput;
}
```

Department BO Class:

```
public class DepartmentsBO
{
    public string dept_id { get; set; }
    public string dept_name { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public Boolean isException { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing? Can you help me out in this scenario.

Comment: Please remove `async: false`. It's considered terrible practice as it locks the browser until the request completes. Do the properties of the `departmentBO` object you send exactly match those of your `DepartmentsBO` class?

Comment: It is working" is a valid json output?i don't think so

Comment: u need to convert your jsonOutput into JSON first, then return it.

Comment: show your DepartmentsBO model as well

Comment: @madalinivascu yes, i know it's not. i have changed the code accordingly to return valid json output. But still no luck.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I have edited accordingly.

Comment: try to declare your isException with `true` or `false`, as its a `boolean` variable

Comment: What do you get in console?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace data with

```
data: "{departmentBO : " + JSON.stringify(departmentBO) + "}",
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simply change your variable like this and it starts working

```
var departmentBO = {
                "dept_id" : "",
                "dept_name" : "",
                "msg" : "",
                "isException" : ""
            };
```

Also there isn't any affect by removing async:false

Comment: I have changed it as well. but still the method is not getting any call.

Answer (score 0):

after trying in several ways what actually solved my problem, I have changed the AJAX parameters as below:

```
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "departmentBO": departmentBO }),
                url: 'AdminPanel.aspx/UpdateDepartmentNameJSON',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Department Name Updated');
                },
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert(xhr.responsetext);
                }
            });
```